# how to prevent jquery validation alerting twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

this jquery validation works however when i select a radio button without selecting a dropdown and click submit it alerts me to select a dropdown but once i click 'ok' it immediately says Please select preference for (USER) which is the next person, how do I remove this.

I have tried using break; after return false; but it just bypasses the validation for radio button

```
$("input:submit").click(function(){  
     if (!$("input[name=attendance1]").is(":checked")) {
        alert('Please select preference for <?php echo $row3['name1']?>');
        return false;
        }
   else if (!$("input[name=attendance2]").is(":checked")) {
        alert('Please select preference for <?php echo $row3['name2']?>');
        return false;
            }
    else if (!$("input[name=attendance3]").is(":checked")) {
        alert('Please select preference for <?php echo $row3['name3']?>');
        return false;
    }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

```
$("input:submit").click(function() {
    var flag = true;

    if (flag && !$("input[name=attendance1]").is(":checked")) {
        alert('Please select preference for <?php echo $row3['
        name1 ']?>');
        flag = false;
    }
    if (flag && !$("input[name=attendance2]").is(":checked")) {
        alert('Please select preference for <?php echo $row3['
        name2 ']?>');
        flag = false;
    }
    if (flag && !$("input[name=attendance3]").is(":checked")) {
        alert('Please select preference for <?php echo $row3['
        name3 ']?>');
        flag = false;
    }

    return (flag);

});
```

​

Comment: It does not work, it does not show any error if no radio buttons are selected and submit is clicked

Comment: are you seeing the same behaviour as original question or absolutely no behaviour? have you checked your browser console if there are any javascript errors?

Comment: no, it just shows no error now when submit is clicked and nothing selected. it says  Expected '}' just after the line above

Comment: so that means there is a JS error. @lukey I can't help you debug a `js` error if I can't see the complete non-private part of the code that interacts with the above code. Could you add as much of your code as possible as an edit to your question?